# How can I increase link speed between two webservers?

Tags: networking, network-speed

There is server **A** in which there is no physical access, in a datacenter around 500Km away. This server is not ours but we are using one of its webservices. And there is the company's server in our offices **B**.

We want link speed between A and B to be the best possible. Even if we have to move it elsewhere.

Because of our location, our ADsl speed is 7mbit down and 0.7 up. This is our bottleneck.

The best scenario till now is to get another dedicated server in the same datacenter, that will act as B.

Then there is the problem, that server A is used by many other companies.

Will this work and if no are there any workournds?

Comment: As you've pointed out, if you move server B to the same data centre as server A, that should surely do it. As you aren't actually interfering with server A I don't understand why there is a problem with other companies using server A? I assume that's the case already?

Comment: There would be a massive load in one time where many companies (around 200) will try to use the service. We want to be able to use the service that A provides. In this situation, being in the same datacenter will help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being in the same datacenter can allow you to set up a 100mbps or even 1000mbps link between servers which will definitely help; However, server A could still be potentially overburdened by requests if its hardware can't keep up, which seems to be out of your control.

Being in the same datacenter will be useful if you're going to need to use more than the 0.7mbps of upload speed you have to send data to server A.